# Add Incrementing ID to each paragraph in the_content

Tags: loop, the-content, php

I need to loop through each paragraph in the_content and add an ID to each paragraph with an incremental value.

```
function incrementparagraphs( $content ) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++) {
        return str_replace( "<p>", "<p data-section-id=" . $i . ">", $content );
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'incrementparagraphs', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code? You are looping via characters of content? Give code above for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'incrementparagraphs', 10, 1 );

function incrementparagraphs( $content ) 
{
     return preg_replace_callback(
         '|<p>|',
         function ( $matches )
         {
             static $i = 0;
             return sprintf( '<p data-section-id="%d">', $i++ );
         },
         $content
     );
}
```

to replace every `<p>` tags with `<p data-section-id="1">`, where the `data-section-id` attribute contains the incremental count of the current `p` tag.

### Example:

**Before:**

```
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc</p>
```

**After:**

```
<p data-section-id="0">aaa</p>
<p data-section-id="1">bbb</p>
<p data-section-id="2">ccc</p>
```

More on `preg_replace_callback` [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).